# How can I redirect users after they logged in with if/else statement (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, authentication

I am learning JavaScript so I decided to make a small project of simple if/else statement login. Everything is fine, but it is not redirecting.

If you know what I am doing wrong please help me in simple language
because I am learning it.

```js
'use strict'
function validate(){
    var username=document.getElementById('login-username').value;
    var passowrd=document.getElementById('login-password').value;

    if (username === "daksh" && passowrd === 'daksh'){
        alert('You have sucessfully logged in');
        window.location.href("http://stackoverflow.com");
    } else{
        alert('Wrong username or password');
        return true;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css">
  <title>Login</title>
  <script src="login.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <DIV class="container">
    <form method="POST" class="login-form">
      <h1 class="login-heading">LOGIN FORM</h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="User Name" id="login-username">
      <br><br>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="login-password">
      <br><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" id="login-submit" onclick="validate()">
    </form>
  </DIV>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `window.location.href` isn't a function, and the error in the browser console should tell you as much. You need `window.location.href = "https://stackoverflow.com";`

Comment: This is probably just a learning project, but for future reference: don't *ever* perform authentication on the client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. ALWAYS use the submit event handler on a form, NEVER the submit button - you want to block the submission in case of error, or in your case blcok because you are handling the processing yourself
2. Use [eventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) instead of inline event handler
3. You use location.href as a function, it is not. You could use `location.replace(href)` if you wish
4. For obvious security reasons, do not do client side passowrd validation, but I assume it is just for learning purposes

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // when the page has loaded
  document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) { // passing the event
    e.preventDefault(); // you do not want to let the form submit because you handle the nex page 
    const username = document.getElementById('login-username').value;
    const password = document.getElementById('login-password').value;

    if (username === "daksh" && password === 'daksh') {
      alert('You have sucessfully logged in');
      window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
    } else {
      alert('Wrong username or password');
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css">
  <title>Login</title>
  <script src="login.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form method="POST" class="login-form" id="myForm">
      <h1 class="login-heading">LOGIN FORM</h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="User Name" id="login-username">
      <br><br>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="login-password">
      <br><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" id="login-submit">
    </form>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you so so much. I was triying to redirect from several days. Can you plz explain more what is event lister and what you did in that that will be really helpful to me

Comment: Here is a good explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events

Answer (score 1):

`window.location.href` is a property, not a method, so your code should be like:

```
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

More info about it on [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

Answer (score 1):

window.location.href is not a function.
You need to assign the url to window.location.href.

```
window.location.href = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
```

However, window.location.href simulates a click. If you want to simulate a HTTP redirect use window.location.replace instead.

```
window.location.replace('http://stackoverflow.com');
```

Edit:
You are also submitting the form, because there is a form method and a submit input specified. This triggers a form post and because no action is specified it will reload the page. Remove the form method and use a button instead.

```js
function validate(){
  var username=document.getElementById('login-username').value;
  var passowrd=document.getElementById('login-password').value;

  if (username === "daksh" && passowrd === 'daksh'){
      alert('You have sucessfully logged in');
      location.href = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
  } else{
      alert('Wrong username or password');
      return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>
  <DIV class="container">
    <form class="login-form">
      <h1 class="login-heading">LOGIN FORM</h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="User Name" id="login-username">
      <br><br>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="login-password">
      <br><br><br>
      <button type="button" value="Login" id="login-submit" onclick="validate()" value="login">Login</button>
    </form>
  </DIV>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thx for tryin g to help me, but i did what u said but the index.html is refreshing instead of redirect.
```
function validate(){
    var username=document.getElementById('login-username').value;
    var passowrd=document.getElementById('login-password').value;

    if (username === "daksh" && passowrd === 'daksh'){
        alert('You have sucessfully logged in');
        window.location.href = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
    } else{
        alert('Wrong username or password');
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah this is because you use form method="POST" and a submit input. When clicking on the submit button the form automatically posts and it (probably) triggers a redirect because no action is given. If you remove method="POST" from the form and replace the input for a button then it will redirect.

Answer (score -2):

This is what you should do as regards redirecting to another page using javascript

#### Here is the index.html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css">
<script src="demo.js"></script>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
     <!-- Form was given an id of 'formLogin' which will be refernced from javascript. -->
     <form  method="POST" class="login-form" id="formLogin">
        <h1 class="login-heading">LOGIN FORM</h1>
         <input type="text" placeholder="User Name" id="login-username">
         <br><br>
         <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="login-password">
         <br><br><br>
         <input type="submit" value="Login" id="login-submit" onclick="validate()">
     </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

From

#### demo.js

javascript file, the below code

```
'use strict'
// a function to validate the fields supplied from the form
function validate(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // this is to prevent the form from refreshing on submitting

//getting the values from the textfields in the form

    let username=document.getElementById('login-username').value;
    let passowrd=document.getElementById('login-password').value;

    // if the name and password matches the required credentials,
    if (username === "daksh" && passowrd === 'daksh'){
        alert('You have sucessfully logged in'); //display a successful login alert
        location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com"; //redirect to the URL specified
    } else{
        alert('Wrong username or password'); // display alert for wrong credentials 
        return false;
    }
}
// Here we are adding an event listener to the form in our index.html file
// When the form is submitted, the custom validate function is called. 
document.getElementById('formLogin').addEventListener('submit', validate);
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).